# Logging Ruby API Request Information to Database

Tags: mysql, ruby, api, logging, sinatra

I'm writing an API in Sinatra and I want to log the requests that are coming into my service to a table in the database. I want to include the following information:

- Date/Time
- Endpoint
- User-Agent
- IP Address
- Payload

What's the best approach here? How can I tap into these and save them off? Maybe there is a gem out there I don't know about.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a way to hook this up with `Logger`, but probably the easiest way to do it would be in an [`after` block](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Filters), e.g.:

```
after do
  # assuming you're using something like AR
  LogObject.create({
    time: Time.now,
    req_path: request.path_info
    # ...
  })
end
```

See [How to dump an HTTP request from within Sinatra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014996/how-to-dump-an-http-request-from-within-sinatra), for a bunch of info you can get from the `request` object.